# Cannot filter in quick edit in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, filter, quick-edit

I have a list which have a lot of data. I can filter list in standard view but when I use quick edit view, just some column can filtered. It's not display "show filter choice" when the column have too many choice. How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: how many items do you have in your list and can you please let us know the  type of column you are facing issues with

Comment: the list has about 10000 items but I filtered items to the view with 2000 items and it still can not filter. Many column has this issue, text, date, choice, ...
I realize which column has a little data will display filter choice but if it has too much data then it will not display "show filter choice" like standard view do.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192939/can-i-still-index-a-column-after-i-reach-5000-documents/192941) deals with a similar kind of issue, it described a limitation of 5000 items in a view.

Read up on [Indexing a column](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0), this may help Sharepoint to permit filtering on your column.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I have to add an answer.

But basically I want to follow up on what Tally said, and say that I've found strange behaviour like this before, and what fixed it for me (apart from indexing) was that the filtering had to be in a particular order. (the indexed filter first)

For instance - if I filtered first by "column A is not empty" then "indexed column > date", it would sometimes have symptoms like you described, but if I filtered first by "indexed column > date" then "column A is not empty", it would be happy.

My guess is that because "column A is not empty" filters down to still over threshold, before the indexed filter takes to under threshold, it bugs out.